# Calling another API within an API gets timeout

Tags: c#, azure, webapi

I have quite a stupid question, but the environment I am working in forced me to use this solution.

1. We have a WebAPI providing data to an angular frontend.
2. For authentication we use an Azure AD B2C Tenant.
3. User sign into frontend and start to receive Data from the API as normal as it should be.

But: The users have to get different data regarding Groups in the Azure AD. So e.g. UserA is in GroupB and has to get other data than UserX who is in GroupY.

So within the api I need to verify that the Users are in the groups for the data they are requesting.
Normaly I would use Microsoft.Graph to communicate with Azure from the API. But as this is a special network I need to go through a proxiy using different User-Agents. This is all working fine when I call my Code from an executable.
But when I call the same Methods within the API I get a timeout and no Data from Azure. I tested the same routines with other APIs and there is no timeout.

I already checked the request Headers to verify that there is no mixed up information or anything, but everything looks like as it should be.

Has anyone had similar Problems, or has a solution regarding the User-Agent when creating the Request Token for API?

Thank you!

Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest debugging your code when you perform the call from your API to Azure. Check if there is anything descriptive that would describe your problem, this could be a response or anything else. You mentioned it is working on an executable, is the api running on the same network as your executable? Perform network tests to check if your api server can reach azure. I am no expert on the technologies but these are things to consider based on the scenario.

Comment: Hi, yes, the code is running on the very same machine. The executable was added to the solution and set as startup-project. As soon as it hits the line with HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content); I can wait for 30 seconds and clack -> Timeout

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on your code when you communicate with azure? Try debugging it first.

Comment: yes. I tried that. at the point where the request is sent, i can wait for 30 seconds to receive the response of the timeout. In Async, there is also an empty return.

Answer (score 0):

Case closed. The proxy denied the request and caused the timeout when called by the api. Don't ask my why. The same code and build is running on the deployed environement with no issues. Who would have thought that there would be the day when I say "But it wasn't working on my machine..."

Cheers!